# Request body size limit

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, httpclient

I get list of entity from queue message(with RabbitMq) and then send it on another API with http client I will get this error but process completely working good and data is sending there can you explain for me why this is happening
[image: error detail]

I reduced the payload size but I still get this error and I do not know why it's properly working

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can experience this when the url parameter is too long. Perhaps you are sending the list as a url parameter. Try change to POST action if you're using GET action.